# Which plot do I need to use to show my data?

Tags: data-visualization, spss, scatterplot

I've checked for which X and Y we get which binary value of another variable. I want to plot these X and Y as axes and show the boundary - a line under which the binary value is 0, above it it's 1. I work with Excel but may use SPSS, better not use R.

Comment: This isn't about which plot to use, a simple scatterplot will be fine. What you need is to calculate the boundary line.

Comment: Take a look at our threads on [binary classification](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=binary%20classification).